# UI or Application layer responsibility - retrieving additional data for display

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns, clean-architecture

I have an application service that retrieves Order data. The service is consumed in UI, where it can be edited by users.

Additionally, the users wants to see related data such as ordered products' descriptions.

Is it UI's responsibility to load the additional data or should I modify the application service to include all related data needed for display?

[image: Architecture]

1. UI (Blazor)
2. Application
3. Domain
4. Infrastructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI should express it’s data needs. It should not reach out and find the data. It should not make decisions with the data. It should sit around waiting for the data to be handed to it. Once handed the data it should just display it as is.

Done this way the UI isn’t something filled with opinions about where stuff is, when to get it, or what to do with it. All that should be handled elsewhere.

A UI is notoriously difficult to test. But keep the UI simple and it’s easy to test because it doesn’t need testing. It’s a pattern Martin Fowler called the
[humble object](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/HumbleObject.html%20https://martinfowler.com/bliki/HumbleObject.htmlBe)

What the UI can do is announce things the user has done to the rest of the system, which can decide, on its own, what, if anything, to do about that.

So if this data must be paired with that data before displaying it let the rest of the system work that out. It’s not a UI thing. The UI just needs to know how to show it once paired.

Comment: Mostly, the additional data doesn't have to be paired before displaying it. They could be asynchronously loaded after the core data is displayed. I find these decisions purely UI concern. Being that said, I understand your arguments

Comment: @liero a purely UI concern is displaying a label or signaling that a user pressed a button. How data should be arranged belongs at least down in view logic and data structures.

Comment: I have trouble to distinguish between UI and View logic